# Page information and some modules not visible

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, cms, permissions

Due to malware attack I have changed the folder and file permission from 777 or 775 to 755 and 644. After this there are some modules and page section in CMS not working properly. I am not able to modify the page. Please help me out from this.

[image: page not visible]

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to make out the exact issue. But you can do one thing is to replace core files of magento under app folder.

This can get it working.

Thank you

Comment: Thank's Bhargav for ur reply. I replaced the core file from app folder but it's Not working. Actually i have issue in page information page or some modules also. when m going to edit the page it's not working properly. earlier i have send the image of page section under cms.